# dissoc in clojure can't get to work

Tags: clojure

I have this function:

```
(defn dissoc-all [m kv]
  (let [[k & ks] kv]
    (dissoc m k ks)))
```

Where `m` is the map and `kv` is the vector of keys. I use it like this:

```
(dissoc-all {:a 1 :b 2} [:a :b])

=>{:b 2}
```

This is not what I've expected. `ks` has `:b` but I don't know why it is not being use by `dissoc`. Anyone can help me with this?

**Edit:** Added question is that why is this not triggering the 3rd overload of `dissoc`, which is `dissoc [map key & ks]`?

Changed name from dissoc-in to dissoc-all as noisesmith have said, -in is not a proper name for this and I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work because `ks` is a collection of all the elements in `kv` after the first. So instead of `:b` it is `[:b]`.

Instead, you can just use apply:

```
(defn dissoc-in [m vs]
  (apply dissoc m vs))
```

Also, `dissoc-in` is an odd name for this function, because the standard functions with `-in` in the name all do nested access, and this does not use the keys to do any nested access of the map.

Comment: Sorry for the name, idk any of the standards. :(

You mean `(:b)`? Also I thought it's gonna go with `dissoc [map key & ks]`?

Comment: Yes, the destructuring will give you a sequence containing `:b` as the binding for `ks` in that example. Due to how Clojure's structural equality works, it can be clearer to indicate `[:b]` as opposed to `(:b)`, which could also be a function call.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like this?

```
(defn dissoc-all [m ks]
  (apply dissoc m ks))

(dissoc-all {:a 1 :b 2} [:a :b])

=> {}
```

The reason the third overlod of `dissoc` is not getting called is because it does not expect a collection of keys like `[:a :b]` - it expects just the keys.

For example:

```
(dissoc {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"} :a :b :c)

=> {:d "d"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to [noisesmith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010400/1562315):

You're being confused by the overloads/arities of `dissoc`, which have this simple effect:

```
[m & ks]

"Returns a new map of the same (hashed/sorted) type,
  that does not contain a mapping for any of ks. "
```

The explicit arities for no keys and one key are for performance. Many clojure functions are so organised, and the documentation follows the organisation, not the underlying idea.

Now, the action of

```
(dissoc-all {:a 1 :b 2} [:a :b])
;{:b 2}
```

is to bind

- `k` to `:a`
- `ks` to `[:b]`

Note the latter. The example removes the `:a` but fails to remove the `[:b]`, which isn't there.

You can use `apply` to crack open `ks`:

```
(defn dissoc-all [m kk]
  (let [[k & ks] kk]
    (apply dissoc m k ks)))

(dissoc-all {:a 1 :b 2} [:a :b])
;{}
```

... or, better, do as @noisesmith does and short-circuit the destructuring, using `apply` at once.